# Включение компьютера через MAC

Tags: delphi, c++

В локальной сети 10 компов, и я знаю мак адреса. Как можно реализовать включение компьютера через MAC адрес? На Delphi или C++ нужно реализовать.

Comment: [Удаленное включение компьютера](https://www.google.ru/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)  
В общем виде задача решается так:
1. Настройка Комп1
2. Послать пакет на включение с Комп2 на Комп

Answer (score 1):

Вы, видимо, хотите реализовать Wake-On-LAN? Тогда посмотрите [здесь](http://www.sysworksoft.net/support/delphiwol.html). WOL на машине должен быть включен.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь: [Wake On LAN](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11469/Wake-On-LAN-WOL).

> В данной статье описываются шаги, необходимые для включения питания на удаленных машинах в локальной сети.